# How to map all image url from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wave-mh1bw)

I am receiving some response from backend.

I am trying to get all images from `imagesData` and show in `ImageComponent` component.

I am using map function in my main component in this way:

```
{!!res &&
    res.map((data) => 
    {
     return <ImageComponent key={data.publicId} {...data} />;
    })}
```

and here is my  `ImageComponent` component:

```
const ImageComponent = ({ img }) => {
  return (
   <div>
     <img src={img} alt="pic" />
   </div>
  );
};
```

But something went wrong please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: A question to your code: does the variable "rest" contain a json object?

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the `map` method on `res`, which is an `object` not an `array`. Map method is made for Arrays. All you have to do is access the image array present in you Object and then, apply the `map`.

Read about map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!!res &&
        res.imagesData.map((data) => {
          return <ImageComponent key={data.publicId} {...data} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
```

In your `ImageComponent`, you have to pass `url` in your destructured props as it is the url property that contains the actual url of your image

```
const ImageComponent = ({ url }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={url} alt="pic" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

res is not an array.

From what I see I suppose you wanted to do this

```
{!!res &&
    res.imagesData.map((data) => 
    {
     return <ImageComponent key={data.publicId} {...data} />;
    })}
```

Comment: yes res in not an array, but my all images are in `imagesData` array, by the way I try as you write but still not working :/ https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-franklin-bowhf

Comment: don't know why but you have res.ImagesData not res.imagesData
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-https-tqrlh